# request http commuication and overload problem

Tags: networking, optimization, flutter

now i am using 2~3 `http` requests every-time when i open flutter app.

```dart
void main() async {
  final List<dynamic> _location = await getGlobalLocation();
  String _time = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm').format(DateTime.now());
  List<dynamic> _Value =
      await getNow(_location[1], _location[2], _time);
  List<dynamic> _aValue = await getNowA();
  List<dynamic> _daysValue = await getdays(_location, _time);
  List<dynamic> _weekTemper = await getWeek(_time);
  runApp(MainPage(_Value, _aValue, _daysValue, _weekTemper));
}
```

like this.
but i think this's too often to server and user making slow. i mean what if the data in server are updated every hour, i don't need to use `http-connection` every time when i open the app. but
 i don't know how to solve that problem.
 should i check the `http` requests? if it does how can i? what method do i use? do i use cookies data? 
i am trying to find that method but i don't know the keywords to googling. there is only how to get `http` request and parse no check the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually not do this many network calls before event the app is rendered properly. You should instead do these calls on your main page and show a progress indicator while the data is being loaded. If you have to do such thing before you main page is loader, you can create a splash screen and load data inside that screen and navigate to main page when all the data is loaded. For this, you can use `Navigator.pushReplacement` to navigate to main page and remove splash screen from navigation stack so that user can't accidentally navigate back to splash.

Comment: thank you for splash screen comment but my question is a little bit different. the data are updated every hour. so if i open app frequently it's not good for server because i demand many requests. in that case is there any method i don't need to request everytime when i open the app?

Comment: Then you can save the data locally along with the last refresh time. When you open the app, you check first if your data is good by checking when was it refreshed last time. If Last refresh time was more than an hour ago, only then you fetch your data from server. Otherwise you’ll use your local storage (SQLite for example).

Comment: thanks you mean save the time with sqlite and check?

Comment: This can be saved in user prefs no need to save it in sqlite

Comment: uhm sorry i can't make image of what you said 'user prefs' what's that mean? how can i?

Comment: shared preferences is basically a dedicated small storage for every app. You can save user settings and cache very basic data in it. So you use SQLite for the actual data but for keeping the 'last updated' time, you can use shared preferences. For details, check this article: https://medium.com/flutter-community/shared-preferences-how-to-save-flutter-application-settings-and-user-preferences-for-later-554d08671ae9